# Microsoft access columns display

Tags: database, ms-access

I want to select a project name and want it to display the number associated with it too, in the same column or another column.

Is there a way to make it display both the name and the number?

If not, how would I make a next cell read the entry from the second column on the `Projects name` cell?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Modify SELECT for combobox, add number as a second field, then set `Column Count' property of combobox to 2,`Column Width` to, let's say 2,1. Now combobox will show two columns.

You can read data from second column of selected item in combobox using

```
Me.MyCombo.Columns(1)
```

Columns numeration starts with 0

Comment: I can't find the select for button for the combo box, Also my column count property of combo box is set to 2 but still displaying the same old (image from original post), Also when I type "Me.MyCombo.Columns(1)" inside the calculation  field it gives me an error. Please advise. 

http://imgur.com/a/4Eu9d
http://imgur.com/a/DEBmE

Comment: Also where do I go to find out the name of my combobox (in the table), Please give step by step advice,

Comment: I don't recommend to edit data directly in the table, my answer was related to the form, not to table. But table also has similar properties, but doesn't have any names for comboboxes and you cannot use any VBA code for table controls like in my answer. Actually you use values list as recordsource, you can switch Row Source Type to `Table/Query` and use SQL for selecting rows for combobox. You can hide unnecessary combobox columns, just use 0 as column width for this column (0",1" in example)